# Xamarin.Forms - How to manage gravity?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am looking for way to manage gravity in xamarin.forms. It's so poor that xamarin.forms technology does not have it build in.

I tried many ways with `StackLayout` and `Vertical` and `HorizontalOptions`. But everything is crap. I just want to have `Label`(gravity left) and `Button` (gravity Right) in the single 'row'.

EDIT: Ok! I made this in other way.. I used Grid..... Here is code:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label
    Text="{Binding ImieNazwisko}"
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
    FontSize="30"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button_Wyloguj" 
        Text="Wyloguj"
        Clicked="Wyloguj_Button_Clicked"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please provide screenshot what you want and what you have tried.

Comment: check it out :)

Comment: Check my answers hope its help you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need a Grid for this, is much simplyer and clear with a StackLayout:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="Text" 
           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
    <Button Text="Button" HorizontalOptions="End" />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check 
HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" for Label and
HorizontalOptions="End" for Button

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label
    Text="{Binding ImieNazwisko}"
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
    FontSize="30" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button_Wyloguj" 
        Text="Wyloguj"
        Clicked="Wyloguj_Button_Clicked"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```